# How to compare between the values of more than 2 variable

Tags: python

```
for word, sentence in tup:
    while True:
        x, y, z = random.sample(range(words_count), 3)
        if list[x] != list[y] != list[z]:
            aya_index += 1
            print('breaking after success')
            break
        else:
            print('continuing as there are similar words')
            continue
    if aya_index > words_count - 1:
        print('breaking after finishing')
        break
```

As you can see, the above code is supposed to loop over `tup` and only increase aya_index if these three variables are not equal, the question is, Is this how to compare between variables or is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: the code shouldnt be working.

Comment: why, can you clarify your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare the three variables you can use:

```
if (x != y) and (y != z) and (x != z) :
   ....
```

Comment: Thanks to Python's operator chaining behaviour, you could write this as `x != y != z != x`, but I'll leave it to someone else to judge whether this is a good idea. :)

Comment: so the parentheses does mean sth, I tried what you are suggesting but without the parentheses and didn't work

Comment: Yeah, I believe the code in this case more readable.

Comment: Unexpectedly your code worked, I don't know what was wrong, I think the operator chaining behavior is not that good, thx anyway